# Fn keys not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I wanted to give Lubuntu a try. Everything works, even audio now, except the volume control with fn keys, and it would be nice to have those back. lol

Running on a Toshiba Satellite C75D-A if that's of any importance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with lubuntu but you can go into System Settings and keyboard layout from there. You can change the controls. from that you can change the Volume Button to something else or modify current controls. If this worked please respond

[image: yeah]

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you not change the volume at all or do you just want the freedom of not holding specific buttons down to change it.

Comment: I can manually change the volume, but I want to be able to change the volume with f9 and f10 like I used to be able to. :)

Comment: I researched a little bit and came out with this url with all the info you need http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187155 I hope I helped let me know if it worked.

Comment: Lubuntu doesn't have this systems settings app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that you do not need to hold the <kbd>fn</kbd> key through the UEFI/BIOS. [Here](https://youtu.be/5Q11yNBd7X4) is a video to show you how.